# how to enter input in python

Tags: python, input

I am taking part in a competition, but have no idea how to make python take the input. Here's a typical [example](http://www.codechef.com/TCFST13/problems/TCFST06#comment-61616) . The site has given example of how to take input but those are using C and Java ( [click here](http://www.codechef.com/help/#hc_inout) ). Please help me figure out how to make python take the input in this case.

Comment: [Either of these](http://ideone.com/Ia1Ru4) will work fine on codechef.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's more than one way to do this.

**Taking input from the intepreter**

For Python 2.x, you can use the [`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) function:

```
my_input = raw_input("Please enter an input: ")
#do something with my_input
```

Note that the input is always *a string*. To retrieve a number, you can use the built-in `int()` function:

```
my_input = int(raw_input("Please enter an input: "))
#do something with my_input
```

As one other answer mentioned, this will throw an error if the input is a float.

There's also another function, `input`, in Python 2.x. However, in this version of Python, `input` evaluates the input, which is a bad idea. It's not recommended to use it.

For Python 3.x, however, you can use the [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#input) function without any problem, since it's a replacement for `raw_input`:

```
my_input = input("Please enter an input: ")
#do something with my_input
```

**Taking input from command line arguments**

You can also retrieve your input from command line arguments, when executing your script like this:

```
$ python my_script.py arg1 arg2
```

The arguments will be stored in the list `sys.argv`. `sys.argv[0]` is the first argument, `sys.argv[1]` is the second argument, and so on.
Example:

```
import sys
my_input = sys.argv[0]
#do something with my_input
```

See the details of it [here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sys.html#sys.argv)
This method works for both versions, Python 3.x and 2.x .

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways is:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

For something more advanced:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [input](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) or [raw_input](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) functions.

**Note:** `input` is prone to security issues, so use `raw_input` instead.

**For example:**

```
inputString = raw_input()
```

this will read the input line and store it in `inputString`. If you want an `int`,

```
inputInt = int(raw_input())
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to take input for a user is using `raw_input`, this will take in user input as a string. Let me demonstrate:

```
>>> var = raw_input("Enter")
Enter>? happy
>>> var
'happy'
```

Notice the quote-marks on happy, this indicates a string. You may also notice, `input`, and yes that *can* be used to take user input, but here is one example where that is a bad idea:

```
>>> a = 2
>>> input("Enter")
Enter>? a+1
3
```

Here, `input` actually gets *evaluated*, since we've already declared `a`, `a + 1 == 3`, and we see that as the output in our console session. *This* later becomes a security concern (you would not want users messing around with your variables), so for user input, `raw_input` is the best choice.

Since you get a `string` from `raw_input`, you can convert it to whatever you like, *if* it can be converted, for example:

```
>>> var = raw_input("Enter")
Enter>? 122
>>> var = int(var)
>>> var
122
```

However, floats will not work with `int`:

```
>>> int('1.223')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.223'
```

You will need to use `float` here, then it works:

```
>>> float('1.223')
1.223
```