# How to add up a variable?

Tags: python, int, sum

I was wondering how I would sum up the numbers they input for n even though it's an input and not int. I am trying to average out all the numbers they input.

```
n=print("Enter as many numbers you want, one at the time, enter stop to quit. ")
a=0
while n!="stop":
    n=input("Start now ")
    a+=1
```

Comment: Then shouldn't the question be: "How to read an int from input?" (Of which there are many related questions.) The summing bit would be `a+=n`.

Comment: Not necessarily, this looks like Python 3 (print is a function).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/19615427/2864740 (has answers for Python 2 and 3)

Comment: There seems to be confusion if this is about Python 2.x or 3.x; make sure to *add* the appropriate tag.

Comment: @user2864740 I don't think you'd use `a+=n` here; it seems as though poster is using `a` to count the number of inputs (which is better done with a list as suggested below)

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.x `input()` *evaluates the input as python code*, so in one sense it will return something that you can accept as an integer to start with, but may also cause an error if the user entered something invalid. `raw_input()` will take the input and return it as a `string` -> evaluate this as an `int` and add them together.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Input_and_Output

Comment: What is "evaluate this as an int"? To *me*, that does not make sense. I was just told it was a string.

Comment: Not in Python3, which looks to be the case here.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off using a `list` to store the numbers. The below code is intended for Python v3.x so if you want to use it in Python v2.x, just replace `input` with `raw_input`.

```
print("Enter as many numbers you want, one at the time, enter stop to quit. ")
num = input("Enter number ").lower()
all_nums = list()
while num != "stop":
    try:
        all_nums.append(int(num))
    except:
        if num != "stop":
            print("Please enter stop to quit")
    num = input("Enter number ").lower()

print("Sum of all entered numbers is", sum(all_nums))
print("Avg of all entered numbers is", sum(all_nums)/len(all_nums))
```

[`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) & [`len`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) are built-in methods on `list`s & do exactly as their name says. The [`str.lower()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) converts a string to lower-case completely.

Comment: How about `while num.lower() != 'stop'`?  That would account for your three plus any other weird case issues.

Comment: @thumbtackthief I did consider that, but somehow messed it up at the end. Code needs a lot of edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possibility.  The point of the `try`-`except` block is to make this less breakable.  The point of `if n != "stop"` is to not display the error message if the user entered "stop" (which cannot be cast as an `int`)

```
n=print("Enter as many numbers you want, one at the time, enter stop to quit. ")
a=0
while n!="stop":
    n=input("Enter a number: ")
    try:
        a+=int(n)
    except:
        if n != "stop":
            print("I can't make that an integer!")

print("Your sum is", a)
```

Comment: Does the number have to be an integer?  What about decimals?

Comment: This code will truncate anything to be an integer.  So no, the number entered does not have to be an integer, but it will be coerced if possible.

Comment: Sorry--I wasn't clear.  I meant that based on the original problem, it seems as though the user would be able to enter decimals, in which case you wouldn't want to convert them to integers.

Comment: "how I would sum up the numbers they input for n even though it's an input and not int." - OP.  True, this code would be more robust if it could accommodate floats or other number types, but I figured simpler is better since the OP appears to be a beginner.

Comment: True, I'm just unclear on what the OP is looking for and whether int was intentional or he/she didn't know better.

Comment: Ask the OP, or provide an answer that handles decimals.